# version code revert back when I export android application

Tags: eclipse, google-play, android-version

I failed to update my app in Google Play as it says I should update the version of my app. I did but I found the version in the manifest xml revert to 1 no matter to what integer I changed to.

What I think is the main cause is that what I did is I copy the entire folder of project and duplicate in eclipse to continue my newer version of app..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I hadn't duplicated my project, but whenever I tried increment the versionCode in my manifest to 5 (my last version being 4) and export the app, the manifest would change back to 4. For me, I found that if I skipped directly to versionCode 6, it worked fine. No idea why.

Answer (score 9):

I experienced the same problem.
I found out that I was editing the wrong **manifest.xml**. 
You need to edit the **manifest.xml** which is located in the **root** directory of your project not the one located in the **/bin** folder. 
Also remember to save the file before exporting your application to **apk**